# How to unselect checkbox when everything deleted?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm trying to unselect the checkbox when all rows are deleted. This is my current code:

```
function removeElements() 
{
    var chxbox= this.form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = chxbox.length; i--; ) {
        if (chxbox[i].name === 'delrow[]') {
            chxbox[i].checked = this.checked;
        }else (chxbox[i].name === 'delrow[]') {
            chxbox[i].checked = this.checked = false;
    }
}
```

This is my checkbox:

```
  <input type="checkbox"  onclick="removeElements.call(this);" />
```

The checked is okay,but the unchecked doens't seem to work.

Comment: `}else (chxbox[i].name === 'delrow[]') {` makes no sense.

Comment: Oh, okay, yes sure I'll create a jsfiddle now.

Comment: This one is almost the same, when all rows are deleted. the selectall checkbox must be false. http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/7Dqqf/82/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked within your fiddle. You should uncheck your "chk[]" checkbox when you have deleted all of your rows.

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }

        //Here..
        if (table.rows.length == 1) {
             var elem = document.getElementsByName("chk[]")[0];
             console.log( elem );
             elem.checked = false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Dqqf/321/

Comment: Hey! you're the best #1

Comment: Glad that i was helpful!

Comment: hey again, how do I disable when I hide the checkboxes?

Comment: If you have the checkbox element in a variable: elem.disabled = true

Comment: Thanks! @Kartal I really apreciate your help!